# Base class to hold collection instances of derived classes

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance

I have a bunch of classes in my C# program that contain a  static member, which is a dictionary collection of all instances of that class - something like this:

```
class A
{
  private static Dictionary<int,A> dict = new Dictionary<int, A>();
  public static A GetInstance(int handle) { return dict[handle];}

  public A(int handle) {this._handle = handle; dict[handle] = this;}
  ~A() { dict.Remove(_handle);}
  private int _handle;

}
```

I've got this duplicated in a number of classes, and would like to factor out this common code, but can't figure out how do this. Putting it into a plain base class does not work, as I want a new collection for each concrete class. I sense there must be a way to do it with generics, but I can't quite see how at the moment.

For example, this is not right:

```
abstract class Base<T>
{
  private static Dictionary<int,T> dict = new Dictionary<int, T>();
  public static T GetInstance(int handle) { return dict[handle];}

  public A(int handle) {this._handle = handle; dict[handle] = this;}
  ~Base() { dict.Remove(_handle);}
  private int _handle;
}

class A : Base<A>
{
}
```

It fails to complile as the constructor of A is not right. Am I missing a trick here?

Comment: Don't do this; it's a memory leak.  Your finalizers will never run.  (and you shouldn't be using finalizers in the first place)

Comment: @SLaks Could this be realized through `IDisposable` implementation instead of finalizers?

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov: It would still be a bad idea.

Comment: This is not a question about resource management; I have intentionally left out details pertaining to that. Telling me not to do something is  not helpful (particularly telling me that I shouldn't be using finalizers).

Answer (score 2):

This is my variant using [`IDisposable` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) implementation:

```
class Base<T> : IDisposable
    where T : Base<T>, new()
{
    private static Dictionary<int, T> dict = new Dictionary<int, T>();
    private static T Get(int handle)
    {
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(handle))
            dict[handle] = new T(); //or throw an exception
        return dict[handle];
    }
    private static bool Remove(int handle)
    {
        return dict.Remove(handle);
    }

    public static T GetInstance(int handle)
    {
        T t = Base<T>.Get(handle);
        t._handle = handle;
        return t;
    }

    protected int _handle;

    protected Base() { }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Base<T>.Remove(this._handle);
    }
}

class A : Base<A> { }
```

And use it then:

```
using (A a = Base<A>.GetInstance(1))
{

}
```

Here you do not have a `public` constructor for any of the classes deriving from `Base<T>`. While static factory `GetInstance` method should be used to create instances. Remember that instances are removed from the dictionary only when `Dispose` method is called, so you should either use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) or call `Dispose` manually.

However I guess you still should take into consideration the comment by SLaks.